# Is a ReactJS built web app save against cache issues?

Tags: reactjs, browser-cache

When I build a react Web App and a customer loads the app (css and js files) in the cache. Is it save against update, so when there is an update, the cache will recreate like adding a version to the files?

Comment: [How to specify a Cache-Control header for index.html in create-react-app](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65528622/2873538)

Comment: I have a payed hoster with limited access to the server settings. So there is no way then?

Comment: I don't understand. What is your question? What is the issue?

Comment: E.g. you have a `users` collection in firestore. You update the app and rename the collection to `newUsers`. When there is a user, that has the old version of the app in the cache, he will add the data to the former `users` collection or will get promoted with error messages, when I restrict the write access to the old collection.